# my .flexslider content does not display in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, flexslider

I added Flexslider to a wordpress theme.
Flexslider works just fine in my HTML mockup, but when implemented into the Wordpress theme, its now not showing any content within the ".flexslider" class selector.

From the frontend it looks as if ".flexslider" has "display: none" property.

Im not using the Wordpress plugin from Woothemes

My integraton looks like this:

```
<script defer src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/flex/jquery.flexslider.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
SyntaxHighlighter.all();
});
$(window).load(function(){
$('.flexslider').flexslider({
slideshow: true,  
controlsContainer: ".flexslider",


   start: function(slider){
     $('body').removeClass('loading');
   }
 });
});
</script>


<!-- Syntax Highlighter -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/flex/js/shCore.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/flex/js/shBrushXml.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/flex/js/shBrushJScript.js"></script>

<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/flex/jquery.flexslider.js">\x3C/script>')</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to use a [jQuery no conlict wrapper](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#jQuery_noConflict_Wrappers).

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$(function(){
SyntaxHighlighter.all();
});
$(window).load(function(){
$('.flexslider').flexslider({
slideshow: true,  
controlsContainer: ".flexslider",


   start: function(slider){
     $('body').removeClass('loading');
   }
 });
});
});
```

Comment: Hmm no it did not do the trick. Great tip though! I did not know about the noConflict Wrappers.

Comment: I now have this, still not working

`<script type="text/javascript">
   jQuery(function(){
     SyntaxHighlighter.all();
   });
   jQuery(window).load(function(){
     jQuery('.flexslider').flexslider({
  slideshow: true,  
  controlsContainer: ".flexslider",


       start: function(slider){
         jQuery('body').removeClass('loading');
       }
     });
   });
 </script>`